# How to locate all occurences of search string

Tags: vim, replace

Using substitution, I want to replace

```
ones(var1.size,var2.size)
```

with

```
np.ones([var1.size,var2.size])
```

I tried using

```
%s/ones(\(\w\+\),\(\w\+\))/np.ones([\1,\2])/gc
```

based on other posts on Stack Overflow, however, Vim is unable to locate all occurrences of the search phrase.

It was able to locate `ones(3,1)` and change it to `np.ones([3,1])`, but it could NOT locate `ones(1,xi.size)`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `\w` doesn't mean what you think it does. `\w` is the same as `[0-9A-Za-z_]`. See `:h magic` in Vim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making it too hard. Here's how I figure out what Vim's going to do, and break it down into simpler steps:

```
/ones(\(.\+\))
```

will select the contents inside the parenthesis, then press <kbd>Return</kbd> so Vim remembers the pattern.

```
:%s//np.ones([\1])/
```

takes the remembered pattern and replaces it. Adjust your flags as necessary beforehand of course.

Simply match `var1.size,var2.size`.

Regular expressions are extremely powerful but can be maddening too, so keep them as simple as possible because the possibility of them doing the wrong thing goes up as complexity increases.

Comment: Refining a search pattern can be helpful. Related [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episode: [Refining search patterns with the command-line window](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/). Using a plugin like [traces.vim](https://github.com/markonm/traces.vim) might also help with previewing substitutions

Comment: @the Tin Man This works almost perfectly, except in some cases. In the search step, `(\(.\+\))` matches the first opening bracket after `ones` and the last closing bracket of the line. However, this closing bracket does not correspond to `ones`. The structure of the line is `some function( ones(arguments) ) `. In this case the search string matches `ones(arguments))`. Notice the extra closing bracket that has been matched.

Comment: @KiranSagar Well, that means the example in your question wasn't accurate, correct?

Comment: @the Tin Man the example was accurate at the time, but now situation has evolved. Earlier I always had cases where the `ones` was located at the end of the line, but now I have some instances where this function call is embedded as arguments to another function.

Comment: On SO, if a situation evolves we create a new question; Questions that evolve are not desirable because we aim for discrete, concise answers, not long drawn out chains of multiple answers to multiple questions.. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310193/128421.

Answer (score 1):

`\w\+` isn't going to match `xi.size` because the latter is two words with a non-word (`.`) in between. You could use `[^,]\+` instead for this narrow case.

Comment: I'd probably do this with a macro, though.

Answer (score 0):

I am using two functions for this:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>r :%s/\<<C-r><C-w>\>//g<Left><Left>
```

Which lets me press `leader+r` to initiate a search and replace the word under cursor.

And

```
:noremap <C-r> "hy:%s/<C-r>h//gc<left><left><left>
```

Which lets me press `ctrl+r` to initate search and replace on the currently selected Visual-mode string.